# Renaming a file in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm 3.4, I want to rename a file on the file tree that appears on the left of the IDE. If I right-click on a file, there is an option to delete it, but not to rename it. Similarly, there is no way of renaming it from the File or Edit menus. Is there a fundamental reason why PyCharm does not allow this from within the IDE, or have I missed the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Renaming files in PyCharm is simple. You simply select `Refactor > Rename` when right-clicking on a file in the tree.

This will open a popup where you can type in the new filename. There are additional options when renaming, such as searching for references and in comments, strings, etc.

**NOTE:** While PyCharm is indexing files, the option is unavailable. Once indexing is finished (can take a while), it becomes available again (thanks @Eric_Sven_Puudist).

Comment: Putting it under the `Refactor` menu seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: I agree with you @TrevorSullivan, at least I would have added the option in the right-click contextual menu of the file explorer.

Comment: The `Refactor` option in right-click menu is not shown when PyCharm is indexing files. After the indexing is complete, everything is as the answer states.

Comment: On the Run & Debug menu of the file renamed still reflects the old name. Is there an option to rename that as well?

Comment: @PyCharm: having to go to stackoverflow to find out how to rename a file is pretty dumb, please fix this! This is not refactoring, it is just a simple rename of a file, this belongs in a standard context menu! And no, I don't agree with the statement "renaming files in Pycharm is simple", it actually is pretty hard, that is why this article is necessary. Think about all the other software on the planet that doesn't need this entry here.

Comment: Doesn't work. File name stays the same after you do this.

Answer (score 12):

You can just  choose the file and hit `shift+F6` rename it then hit refactor

Comment: Of course! So intuitive ;-) Seriously though, nice shortcut.